# Qual é a melhor maneira de identificar o valor semântico de uma frase?

Tags: preposições, semântica

Estou com dificuldades de identificar o valor semântico da preposição. Analisando uma frase:

`“Transcorridos os nove meses de gravidez, ele nasceu.”`

Penso que `de gravidez`, possui o valor semântico de tempo, mas acredito estar errado. Qual seria a melhor maneira para identificar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, **"nove meses" é que expressa o tempo.**

**"de gravidez" significa um estado**, o estado de estar grávida.

Foram nove meses nesse estado, até que ele nasceu.

Nesse caso, a preposição "de" introduz um estado. Exemplos semelhantes:

- Cem anos de solidão.
- Um ano de separação.
- O vigésimo mês de gestação.
- Oito anos de escravidão.